# enable X-Frame-Options header in spring-boot application (without spring security)

Tags: java, spring, http, security, clickjacking

Security team tested our application and the found following warning:

> X-Frame-Options header is not included in the HTTP response to protect
>   against 'ClickJacking' attacks.

We use spring boot in our application but we don't use spring security. We use our custom security mechanism.

Is there way to add this header into all responses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom filter and set header there:

```
public class XFrameFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
                                    HttpServletResponse httpResponse,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        httpResponse.setHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "DENY");

        filterChain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already setup security config which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
then you just need to add

http.headers().frameOptions().deny();
or
http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();