# Set X-Frame Options to allow in Spring Boot without spring security

Tags: spring-boot, x-frame-options

I am building a small spring boot/ angular app that will be diplayed inside an iframe of another app. Basically a small tool for adding / editing contracts. I have not implemented spring security, because the whole authentication thing is done by the parent app. There is only 1 way to reach my app, through that another app. The parent app will send me the login and thats all.
The problem is, I cannot open my app inside the another, because of the x-frame-options: deny header. Is there a way to change this header without implementing the whole spring security thing. Or maybe implementing only the HttpSecurity part with disabling x-frame-options. Implementing the whole spring security would be an overkill for that small app, so I really hope there is some another option in spring boot, or maybe server side (WildFly 20).
I am using spring boot 2.7.0.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried Vadym Dudnyk-s answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822540/enable-x-frame-options-header-in-spring-boot-application-without-spring-securit ,no success.

Comment: Well I just googled a little bit and found out, that property x-frame-options doesn't support "allow" parameter...so I need to change my question to: How can I inject my app, e.g. https://myapp.com inside an iframe of another app with different domain, e.g. https://parentapp.com. There is no way of putting my app in their server, so there must be an another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors directive it will override X-Frame-Options (Except for IE, which no longer should be a problem). You need to find a way to set the header in the same response as X-Frame-Options, this could likely be in code, webserver, proxy, or a load balancer. In the frame-ancestors directive, list the host names of all allowed hosts.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've added Content-Security-Policy to the overrided doFilterInternal method. Works like a charm :)